Use managed identity to access storage account with persistent volume in AKS
I face the following situation:
I would like to access a storage account using Persistent Volume (PV) and Persistent Volume Claim (PVC) but without an access to the storage account's access key. Hence, I would like to create the PV and PVC using my managed identity.
I have already created my user-assigned managed identity and added that to my Azure Kubernetes Services (AKS) cluster following this documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-managed-identity#enable-a-user-assigned-managed-identity
How should I create the PV and PVC in order to use that managed identity?
I do not find any documentation about that.
Thanks a lot!

As you have mentioned you have already enabled managed identity, get the client ID from there and update it in your pv
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: azurefile-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  csi:
    driver: file.csi.azure.com
    readOnly: false
    volumeHandle: arkostorageaccount1#arkofilefileshare
    volumeAttributes:
      resourceGroup: arkorg
      storageAccount: arkostorageaccount1
      shareName: arkofilefileshare
      useAAD: "true"
      azureStorageIdentityClientID: dabcd-ab67-43e2-1234-7a35eb645f4b  # Use your managed identity Client ID here

Assign the necessary role so it can access the Azure Storage Account.

Apply the updated PV and the PVC
pvc
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: azurefile-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
  volumeName: azurefile-pv


References:

Use a managed identity in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)
Create and use a volume with Azure Disks in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)


If you don't want to add a secret manually, the CSI driver will use the kubelet identity, which is a user-assigned managed identity created by AKS at cluster creation (unless you specified your own). This managed identity is primarily used by the kubelet to access Azure Container Registry (ACR), but it can also be used for authentication to Azure storage for persistent volume mounting.
To view the kubelet identity details:
az aks show --resource-group <your-resource-group> --name <your-cluster-name> --query "identityProfile.kubeletidentity"

You need to assign the correct role to the kubelet identity to allow it to retrieve storage access keys.
To assign the Storage Account Key Operator Service Role:
az role assignment create --assignee <kubelet-identity-client-id> --role "Storage Account Key Operator Service Role" --scope /subscriptions/<your-subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<storage-resource-group>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<your-storage-account>

Ensure that you do not have a secret named azure-storage-account-{accountname}-secret in the pod namespace and omit the nodeStageSecretRef field in the persistent volume configuration, because as the the azurefile-csi-driver doc says:


if the nodeStageSecretRef field is not specified in the persistent volume (PV) configuration, the driver will attempt to retrieve the azure-storage-account-{accountname}-secret in the pod namespace.
If azure-storage-account-{accountname}-secret in the pod namespace does not exist, the driver will use the kubelet identity to retrieve
the account key directly from the Azure storage account API, provided
that the kubelet identity has reader access to the storage account.


Additionally,I want to make clear that, when you create an AKS cluster, it sets up two managed identities by default:

Control plane managed identity: A system-assigned identity used to manage cluster resources such as load balancers and scaling node pools.
Kubelet identity: A user-assigned identity used primarily to interact with ACR, but also to manage volume mounting from storage accounts.

